# Hugo on S3 with CloudFront doesn't redirect to index.html. Terraform config

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, terraform, amazon-cloudfront, hugo

I have a Hugo website that I'm trying to deploy to S3, with a cloudfront distribution. I'm doing the config with Terraform. So far this is what I have (I excluded the certificates/domain parts, they work):

s3.tf:

```yaml
resource "aws_s3_bucket" "my_site_bucket" {
  bucket = var.domain_name
  tags = local.storage_tags
}

data "aws_iam_policy_document" "s3_bucket_policy" {
  statement {
    sid = "1"

    actions = [
      "s3:GetObject",
    ]

    resources = [
      "arn:aws:s3:::${var.domain_name}/*",
    ]

    principals {
      type = "AWS"

      identifiers = [
        aws_cloudfront_origin_access_identity.origin_access_identity.iam_arn,
      ]
    }
  }
}

resource "aws_s3_bucket_policy" "s3_bucket_policy" {
  bucket = aws_s3_bucket.my_site_bucket.id
  policy = data.aws_iam_policy_document.s3_bucket_policy.json
}
```

cloudfront.tf:

```yaml
resource "aws_cloudfront_distribution" "my_cloudfront" {
  depends_on = [
    aws_s3_bucket.my_site_bucket
  ]

  origin {
    domain_name = aws_s3_bucket.my_site_bucket.bucket_regional_domain_name
    origin_id   = "s3-cloudfront"

    s3_origin_config {
      origin_access_identity = aws_cloudfront_origin_access_identity.origin_access_identity.cloudfront_access_identity_path
    }
  }
  enabled             = true
  is_ipv6_enabled     = true
  default_root_object = "index.html"
  aliases             = [var.domain_name]

  restrictions {
    geo_restriction {
      restriction_type = "none"
    }
  }

  default_cache_behavior {
    allowed_methods  = ["GET", "HEAD"]
    cached_methods   = ["GET", "HEAD"]
    target_origin_id = "s3-cloudfront"

    forwarded_values {
      query_string = false

      cookies {
        forward = "none"
      }
    }

    viewer_protocol_policy = "redirect-to-https"
    min_ttl                = 0
    default_ttl            = 3600
    max_ttl                = 86400
  }
  price_class = "PriceClass_200"

  viewer_certificate {
    cloudfront_default_certificate = true
    acm_certificate_arn            = aws_acm_certificate.my_site.arn
    ssl_support_method             = "sni-only"
    minimum_protocol_version       = "TLSv1"
  }

  tags = local.cdn_tags
}

resource "aws_cloudfront_origin_access_identity" "origin_access_identity" {
  comment = "access-identity-${var.domain_name}.s3.amazonaws.com"
}
```

When I deploy my hugo website with this config, it "kinda works". The root URL `fancydomain.com` works, and the root `index.html` is rendered in the browser. However when I click on a link, say `fancydomain.com/blog/post-1`, I'm getting a key error, access denied message. When I enter the url `fancydomain.com/blog/post-1/index.html`, the page displays as expected. I researched this problem, it was mentioned many times before. I tried all the possible combinations of the answers I could find and I never managed to get it to work.
I understand the error: cloudfront is trying to access a file with a specific key, e.g: `s3://fancydomain.com/blog/post-1`, and it doesn't exist. `s3://fancydomain.com/blog/post-1/index.html` does exist though.

I don't know how to fix my terraform config. Would you be able to help please?

Comment: Can you add `s3:ListBucket` to the bucket policy, but for the entire bucket, i.e., `arn:aws:s3:::${var.domain_name}`?

Comment: Nope, it didn't work

Comment: Correction: yeah, I think I need this. I added this, changed the principal to "*" (effectively making the bucket public), I removed the origin_access_identity from cloudfront, added a aws_s3_bucket_website_configuration with a routing rule and it works. But now I need to fix the access, I can't let that be public

Answer (score 0):

You must add

```
resource "aws_s3_bucket_public_access_block" "bucket_restriction" {
  bucket = var.your_bucket_information.id

  block_public_acls = true
  block_public_policy = true
  ignore_public_acls = true
  restrict_public_buckets = true
  depends_on = [
    aws_s3_bucket_policy.web_distribution
  ]
}
```

This is how we create the restrictions to avoid access with the URL generated by S3.

Comment: It doesn't solve the problem unfortunately. I just added that to s3.tf and redeployed, but it doesn't help. Sorry :/